# php mysql info retrieve

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
if ($cuser->loggedin()){
    if (!empty($_POST['returnto']))
    {
        header("Location: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['returnto']));
    }
    else
    {
        $query = ("SELECT id, username, check FROM users WHERE id=".$CURUSER['id']);
        $result = do_mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if ($row['check'] == true) {
        echo 'omg';
    } else {
echo 'omg false';


    }
    //To stop script executing next code ant print info...
    die();
}

    }

    die();
}
```

But always get: **omg** even if i chnage it to false. Any ideas ?

Comment: What is your field type on your database field?

Comment: Even if you change what to `false`? `$row['check']`?

Comment: How your table `users` looks like? what are you storing in `check` column? Provide more information.

Comment: Do a var_export($row['check']) in order to see what is the exact contents of this field.

Comment: Mhmm, i think problem would be with that: ALTER TABLE users ADD check enum('true','false') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false' <== created new column

Comment: I'd just like to add that you shouldn't use htmlspecialchars() on data for a header field.  Headers aren't HTML, and if something (such as an ampersand) actually gets encoded URL style, it's likely to mess something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always **TRUE** in your case

```
if ($row['check'] == true) {...}
```

same as

```
if ($row['check']) {...}
```

Check for a `$row['check']` value instead...

```
if ($row['check'] == 'true') {...}
```

...if you have strings `true` and/or `false` as values of `check` column.

Comment: Or `if( !empty($row['check']) ) { //... }` should also be fine in this case.

Comment: Storing 'true' and 'false' in columns is of course inefficient and silly, use a MySQL boolean and test for 0 = false and !0 = true. Always **store** 1 for true though.

Comment: @Johan Given that he's using an enum, that's effectively what he's already doing.

Answer (score 2):

When you get results with `mysql_fetch_assoc`, the types of the values in the array will almost always be strings (they may occasionally be `null`, but that's not the problem here).

Any non-empty string will evaluate to `true` if you compare them with the `==` comparison operator.

The actual value being returned will not be `true`.  It may be a string containing the word `true` or the word `false`.  However, both of these will evaluate to `true` when compared to the boolean `true`.

Exactly what you should compare against depends upon what's in your database...

---

Your comment suggests that the field is an enum.  This gives you two possible strings, `"true"` and `"false"`.  Since in PHP `"false" == true` is correct behaviour (because non-empty strings evaluate to `true`), you need to compare against a string value instead:

```
if ($row['check'] == "true") {
```

Comment: OMG, `"false" == true` that is so borken (LOL)